# Need good MVVM tutorial for WPF

Tags: wpf, mvvm

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [MVVM: Tutorial from start to finish?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1405739/mvvm-tutorial-from-start-to-finish)

i just started learning WPF. i need to learn MVVM patter and want to implement MVVM in my WPF crud application. so anyone please guide me how could i develop a CRUD apps in WPF following MVVM pattern. thanks

Comment: This goes from basic to advance http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/819294/Learn-WPF-MVVM-step-by-step-Basics-to-Advance-Leve

Comment: I found http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/ and http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/819294/WPF-MVVM-step-by-step-Basics-to-Advance-Level  those are reasonably good

Comment: Can't post on duplicate because it is close (even though they have over 370K views together...). For my kind of learning process ,Reed Cospey's [blog](http://reedcopsey.com/series/windows-forms-to-mvvm/) was just incredibly educational.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Probably the single most important MVVM article is Josh Smith's article from the MSDN magazine:

- [WPF Apps With The Model-View-ViewModel Design Pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx) by Josh Smith

This article has a very nicely designed example application that accompanies it. However, it is a bit light in some areas. Another pair of articles I really like are:

- [MVVM for Tarded Folks Like Me](http://jmorrill.hjtcentral.com/Home/tabid/428/EntryId/432/MVVM-for-Tarded-Folks-Like-Me-or-MVVM-and-What-it-Means-to-Me.aspx)
- [How Tards Like Me Make MVVM Apps](http://jmorrill.hjtcentral.com/Home/tabid/428/EntryId/433/Anatomy-of-an-MVVM-Application-or-How-Tards-Like-Me-Make-MVVM-Apps.aspx)

They are a bit more light in nature.

---

You can find more information relevant to your question [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1405739/mvvm-tutorial-from-start-to-finish).

Comment: I always wonder why Microsoft webpages, case in point MSDN Magazine, give little to no importance to how code is displayed on the page where it should be the first thing that should be displayed correctly. Why Microsoft? Why?